# ens.setup_address using signed transaction and Infura

Tags: web3.py, infura

I have a python application and I don't have a local node. I want to use Inufra.
I've created an ens name in the Ropsten network and I want to create users in my system and create a sub ens name using a signed transaction.

Here is my code:

```
        eth_wallet = w3.eth.account.create(password)
        transaction = {
            'to': settings.RESOLVER_ADDRESS,  # resolver
            'from': settings.MAIN_ADDRESS,
            'value': 0,
            'nonce': w3.eth.getTransactionCount(settings.MAIN_ADDRESS),
            'gas': 100000,
            'gasPrice': settings.CONTRACT_DEPLOY_GAS
        }
        private_key = settings.ADDRESS_PRIVATE_KEY
        signed = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(transaction, private_key)
        ns.setup_address(
            f"{username}.{settings.USER_MAIN_ENS_DOMAIN}",
            eth_wallet,
            signed,
        )
```

I always got an error that I am not an owner and I cannot perform any modification. I ran some debugging and the reason is that my `settings.MAIN_ADDRESS` not in `w3.eth.accounts`.

I checked this github issue and tried to monkey patch the second called method in ns.setup_address which is `self._assert_control(owner, name)`. I added `ns._assert_control = lambda *_: True` to my code, but it didn't help.
I got a new error:

```
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ens/main.py", line 329, in _claim_ownership
    transact['from'] = old_owner or owner
TypeError: 'SignedTransaction' object does not support item assignment
```

Is it supposed to work with signed transactions? I guess it expects transact as a dict, not a signed transaction.

**UPDATE::**
I added a middleware that is supposed to sign my transactions.

```
w3.middleware_onion.add(construct_sign_and_send_raw_middleware(private_key))
eth_wallet = w3.eth.account.create(password)
transaction = {
                'to': settings.RESOLVER_ADDRESS,  # resolver
                'from': settings.MAIN_ADDRESS,
                'value': 0,
                'nonce': w3.eth.getTransactionCount(settings.MAIN_ADDRESS),
                'gas': 100000,
                'gasPrice': settings.CONTRACT_DEPLOY_GAS
            }
private_key = settings.ADDRESS_PRIVATE_KEY
ns.setup_address(
                f"{username}.{settings.USER_MAIN_ENS_DOMAIN}",
                eth_wallet,
                transact,
            )
```

It leads to an error from Infura:

`{'code': -32601, 'message': 'The method eth_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available'}`

I found an answer from the Infura community: https://community.infura.io/t/the-method-eth-sendtransaction-does-not-exist-is-not-available/1537

I guess that middleware doesn't really sign my transaction